# What is the equivalent of fullpage in geometry package?

Tags: margins, geometry

There's an occasion when I am forced to use `geometry` package instead of `fullpage`. However the document margins should match another document which uses `fullpage`.

Where can I find the default top, bottom, right, left values when simply using `fullpage`?
The document class is `article`.

Comment: The [`fullpage` README](http://ctan.org/pkg/fullpage) mentions "This pack­age sets all 4 mar­gins to be ei­ther 1 inch or 1.5 cm", which is straight-forward in [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) via the `margin` key-value.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The only difference between

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[
  margin=1.5cm,
  includefoot,
  footskip=30pt,
]{geometry}
\usepackage{layout}

\begin{document}
\layout
\end{document}
```

and

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\usepackage{layout}

\begin{document}
\layout
\end{document}
```

seems to be that the head height and the head separation in `fullpage` are zero.

For the `in` default option, change `margin=1.5cm` into `margin=1in`.

---

Just for experimenting, I compiled the same document with both preambles; the one with `geometry` with red text. I converted the DVI files to PNG with transparent background with `dvipng`. Next I superimposed the two PNG files in a single document. Here's the picture showing no essential difference between the two.

[image]

Comment: This does not produce the same output as using fullpage. Specifically, the margins of the abstract are different. I tried both cm and inch.

Comment: @EllaSharakanski I can see no difference whatsoever. Are you using `article` or a different class?

Comment: @EllaSharakanski See the result of the experiment.

Answer (score 19):

I have found that loading `geometry` with the `[pass]`option gives you access to all the features of the `geometry` package (at least the ones I use), without changing the extant page dimensions.  Thus you can get the dimensions of the `fullpage` package, with the features of the `geometry` package available.

The `pass` option disables most of the *options* (not *features*), except `verbose` and `showframe`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[pass, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-7]
\newgeometry{margin=2in}
\lipsum[8-10]
\end{document}
```

Page 1 has the default `fullpage` dimensions (with `showframe`), but that has been reset on page 2 with a `\newgeometry` command, courtesy of the `geometry` package.

[image]