# Emulating article class margins with the geometry package

Tags: margins

I apologize if this is an obvious question, haven't been able to find a straightforward answer to it. My issue is this: I prefer standard article class margins, yet I need to use the geometry package to change margins on a single page so that a graph would fit. The geometry package sets, however, its own margins, which are too small for my taste.

Now, surely, it is possible to simply reproduce the original article class layout with the geometry package. How would one go about it? The geometry package seems to use another specification system.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `\usepackage[pass]{geometry}` will load the package, but leave existing settings intact.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179116/what-is-the-equivalent-of-fullpage-in-geometry-package/179122#179122

Comment: `\newgeometry` is like a sledgehammer and there are often lighter ways to locally obtain different margins.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes This indeed achieves the desired effect. Thank you. Perhaps translate it into an answer?

Comment: @egreg Would you care to elaborate? If even simply with a link to additional material? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `[pass]` option to the `geometry` package will load the features of the package, while leaving the existing settings of the underlying class intact.  When using the `pass` option, most of the other package *options* (not *features*) are disabled.

The MWE below shows how the default `article` settings are adopted on page 1, but that a `\newgeometry` command is available for changing the settings on page 2.  The `showframe` option is employed to show the margin settings.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pass, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\newgeometry{margin=0.5in}
\lipsum[4-6]
\end{document}
```

[image]