# Alter single margin using Geometry package

Tags: margins, geometry

I want to adjust only the top margin (using Article class). All other margins should remain the same. How do I use the geometry package to do this? As soon as I load the geometry package it changes all margins to its own defaults. I guess the answer is too re-specify the Article margins using the geometry options but I don't know what exact margins I would need to put there.

My question is close to [Emulating article class margins with the geometry package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209887/emulating-article-class-margins-with-the-geometry-package). However, it differs in that I do want to set the same margins for the whole document. I just want to only alter one margin without affecting the others.

---

In the log I find for an article:

```
* \paperwidth=614.295pt
* \paperheight=794.96999pt
* \textwidth=345.0pt
* \textheight=550.0pt
* \oddsidemargin=62.0pt
* \evensidemargin=62.0pt
* \topmargin=16.0pt
* \headheight=12.0pt
* \headsep=25.0pt
* \topskip=10.0pt
* \footskip=30.0pt
* \marginparwidth=65.0pt
* \marginparsep=11.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=9.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidefalse
* \@mparswitchfalse
* \@reversemarginfalse
```

I started putting this as input into `\geometry` but it is not immediately clear to me how to do this for all the settings. I seem to be using some of them wrong.

I get close to the article style again using:

```
\geometry{paperwidth=614.295pt, paperheight=794.96999pt,textwidth=345.0pt, textheight=550.0pt, 
headheight=12.0pt, headsep=25.0pt,
footskip=30.0pt, marginparwidth=65.0pt, marginparsep=11.0pt, columnsep=10.0pt}
```

Some names as presented here do not seem to match the input form in geometry. For instance oddsidemargin=62.0pt does not work. I also tried the top margin by setting top=16.0pt. This clearly gives the wrong result.

Comment: Maybe this in the preamble, with or without the `geometry` package: `\headheight=\dimexpr\headheight-1in\relax
\textheight=\dimexpr\textheight+1in\relax`

Comment: Also, if you want to load `geometry` without disturbing the predefined documentclass settings, use the `pass` option of `geometry`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179116/what-is-the-equivalent-of-fullpage-in-geometry-package/179122#179122

Comment: you can try `\topmargin=\dimexpr<NewValue>-1in\relax` before `\usepackage[pass]{geometry}` or don't load it at all.

Comment: @touhami But you need to change the text block height, too, to keep the bottom margin the same, don't you?

Comment: If you use `\usepackage[pass,verbose]{geometry}`, you can get the exact default values from the console or log. You can then remove `pass` and use these values, along with the `top` of your choice, to set the margins.

Comment: @cfr oh yes, i didn't see it before.

Comment: theoretically you can do `\textheight=\dimexpr\textheight+\topmargin+1in-<NewValue>\relax
\topmargin=\dimexpr<NewValue>-1in\relax
\usepackage[pass]{geometry}`

Comment: @Steven, as far as I can see the pass option won't really help me out here since what I wanted is not that some part of the document remains unaffected while I use geometry for another part. I uniformly want to change only one margin throughout the document. Am I wrong?

Comment: I only mention the `pass` option as a way to load the package without disturbing the existing geometry, if you you need to load `geometry` for other reasons.  The actual changing of a single margin throughout the document was suggested by either my initial comment or later by touhami.