# Help with making a package

Tags: formatting, package-writing

I'm trying to design a package so that I can 'theme' a document quickly. I've done this, but as a sort of academic exercise I'm trying to design an option `compact` that adjusts margins, title, and layout to optimize the document for use of `multicols`.

The issue here is I want to use `geometry` to define the margins, but do not want to load the`geometry` package otherwise. I have a little bit of a workaround by using `\PassOptionsToPackage`, but then the package is loaded even when the option is not selected and it changes LaTeX's default margins which I don't want to change in this default mode. Ideally, the `textpos` and `multicol` packages wouldn't be loaded unless the option is selected either, because they are otherwise unnecessary.

## What is the most correct way of accomplishing this?

---

**The custom package**:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]

\RequirePackage{graphics}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage{libertine}

\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}

\newcommand{\fullline}{%
    \noindent\rule{\linewidth}{.4pt}\\
    \vspace{-\baselineskip}\\
}

\newcommand{\stretchtitle}[1]{
    \vspace*{-5\baselineskip}\noindent\hspace*{-.75in}
    \resizebox{\dimexpr1.25in+\linewidth}{!}{\textsc{#1}}
    \vspace{\baselineskip}\\
}

\newcommand{\header}[1]{%
    \noindent{\sf\huge\\\\\noindent%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]%
        \draw[right] (-.4em,.5em) node {#1};%
        \draw[line width=1pt] (-.4em,-2em) -- (-.4em,0em) -- (\dimexpr.4em+\linewidth, 0);%
    \end{tikzpicture}}\vspace{-1.25\baselineskip}\\\par\noindent%
}

\newcommand{\leveltwo}[1]{%
    \vspace{\baselineskip}\noindent{\Large\sf#1\normalsize\\\rule{.5\linewidth}{1pt}}
}

\RequirePackage[absolute]{textpos}
\RequirePackage{multicol}

\DeclareOption{compact}{
    \PassOptionsToPackage{margin=.62in}{geometry}
    \setlength{\columnsep}{18pt}
    \setlength{\TPHorizModule}{\paperwidth}
    \setlength{\TPVertModule}{\paperheight}
    \renewcommand{\stretchtitle}[1]{
        \newcommand{\titlewidth}{3.37in}
        \begin{textblock}{.88235294}(0.058823,0.045454545)
            \noindent
            \resizebox{\titlewidth}{!}{\Huge{\textsc{#1}}}\\
            \rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
            \normalsize
        \end{textblock} 
        \vspace*{.5in}
    }
}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\RequirePackage{geometry}
```

**MWE for custom package use**:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{heavymodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \stretchtitle{Minimum Working Example}

    \header{Example}%
    \lipsum[1]

    \leveltwo{Second-Level Example}

    \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: See [Loading a package conditionally](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1273/5764), which states the use of an `\if...\fi` condition.

Comment: Use the `[pass]` option to geometry (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179116/what-is-the-equivalent-of-fullpage-in-geometry-package/179122#179122).  It loads the package without changing the existing parameters of the page.

Comment: Don't use `\sf`. It was deprecated 20+ years ago. Use `\sffamily` or `\textsf{}`.

Comment: @cfr oops... it's faster to type so I get lazy when I know I'm just going to be using `article`... but that's embarrassing...

Comment: @Werner Thank you, that's a helpful answer, but in my case I want to manipulate the packages within the option definition, so I don't know how to make the program flow so that it will work. I'll read more on `\if` switches though.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thanks, that doesn't feel like a full solution but it works for this.

Comment: @Ryan As seen in the cited example, you can invoke it with `[pass]` to stake out access to the package macros without changing the geometry.  Then, and only if needed, you can issue a `\newgeometry` to change the page parameters.  You can even save the old parameters before using a `\newgeometry` so that you can later return to the original settings.

Comment: @Ryan The answer Werner linked to shows you how to process it as part of the option definition i.e. by manipulating `\if` switches. You can combine that with the `pass` option of new geometry so that the margins are only altered `\ifsomeoptionispassed`.

Comment: Are there any news here? Did the linked question already answer your question )making this here a duplictae) or do you need further help? If so, please add a bit more information to the question on where you are stuck.

Comment: One of the links worked, yes, maybe this title should be changed to "how to load packages conditionally within a package" or something and then marked as duplicate to help other people search for this problem. I'm not sure what to change the title to, as I had trouble searching for the answer myself.